# Calculate number of days between dates with DateTime

Tags: perl

I have 2 dates using the DateTime object and in trying to get the difference in days only using delta_days, it isn't working properly.  I thought it would give me the total days, but it looks like its not including the months worth of days.

```perl
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

my $parseseq = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d');
my $todaydate = "20190326";
my $lastdate  = "20190223";

my $currmark = $parseseq->parse_datetime($todaydate);
$currmark->set_formatter($parseseq);
my $lastmark = $parseseq->parse_datetime($lastdate);
$lastmark->set_formatter($parseseq);
my $diff = $currmark->subtract_datetime($lastmark);
my $diffdays = $diff->delta_days();
print "\ntodaydate $todaydate\n";
print "lastdate  $lastdate\n";
print "Diff Days $diffdays\n\n";
```

Output:

```
todaydate 20190326
lastdate  20190223
Diff Days 3
```

Comment: Are you sure your dates got parsed correctly? I.e. can you f.ex. print `$curmark` and `$lastmark` as ISO-8601 timestamps?

Comment: According to the documentation ISO-8601 is the default formatter, so all needed would be to comment out the `->set_formatter()` calls and then `print "$currmark\n";`

Comment: What do you get if you add `use Data::Dumper;`and `my %deltas = $diff->deltas(); print Dump(\%deltas);`? If I understand the documentation correctly `->delta_days()` only returns the days difference, not the **whole** difference in days.

Comment: I tried removing the set_formatter but the result is the same.  I believe that your right, its not giving the whole difference in days as this is the output from the dump

Comment: $VAR1 = {
          'seconds' => 0,
          'minutes' => 0,
          'nanoseconds' => 0,
          'days' => 3,
          'months' => 1
        };

Comment: what makes this strange is that if you change the 2nd date from 20190223 to 20190228 it does return the number of days, not weeks.

Comment: The problem is that you are looking for an *absolute* duration (i.e. # of days), but `subtract_datetime()` doesn't return that (it returns a duration of 1 month and 3 days). Please read the accepted answer of the duplicate link. It should solve your issue.